# UIBarButtonItem target/action not working

Tags: objective-c, action, uibarbuttonitem, target

I am implementing a view with a date picker and a toolbar.
I have the following code:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(frame), 44)];
        UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                                      target:self
                                                                                      action:@selector(didSelectCancelButton)];
        UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                                    target:self
                                                                                    action:@selector(didSelectDoneButton)];

        NSArray *buttons = @[cancelButton, flexible, doneButton];
        [self.toolbar setItems:buttons
                      animated:NO];

        self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, CGRectGetWidth(frame), 216)];


        [self addSubview:self.datePicker];
        [self addSubview:self.toolbar];

    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)didSelectCancelButton {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(datePickerDidCancelDateSelection:)]) {
        [self.delegate datePickerDidCancelDateSelection:self];
    }
}

- (IBAction)didSelectDoneButton {
    NSLog(@"");
}
```

But when I click the buttons, no action is performed. The methods are not invoked.
Can you tell what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

EDIT:
Turned out there was a gesture recognizer that was capturing the touch events.
Fixing that resolved this problem.

Comment: can you edit your question to show what your "`didSelectDoneButton`" and "`didSelectCancelButton`" methods (or, at least the declarations) look like?

Comment: Are the two action methods part of this `UIView` class?

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried pasting your sample code into my own UIView subclass, added the two selectors and tested it... it worked fine.  You need to show more of your code if we're going to help.

Comment: I'm doing this on a view that is being presented modally, can that be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your date picker (which is as wide as the toolbar is) is somehow inhibiting your buttons from getting user touches.

Try reversing these two lines to this:

```
[self addSubview:self.datePicker];
[self addSubview:self.toolbar];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any UIGestureRecognizer objects, if you do try to disable them and test.